# How can I give element a unique id to use it in className?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to toggle class only for clicked element in a component and wanted to use something like id for this but I'm not sure how can I give element an id and use it in className. Here's what I would do if I could get an id from className:

```
function Paginator() {

    const [active, setActive] = useState('');

    const toggleClass = (id) => {
        setActive(id);
    }

    return(
        <div className='pagination'>
            <a id='prev' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">&laquo;</a>
            <a id='1' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">1</a>
            <a id='2' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">2</a>
            <a id='3' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">3</a>
            <a id='4' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">4</a>
            <a id='5' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">5</a>
            <a id='6' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">6</a>
            <a id='7' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">7</a>
            <a id='8' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">8</a>
            <a id='9' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">9</a>
            <a id='10' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">10</a>
            <a id='next' className={active === id ? 'active' : ''} onClick={() => toggleClass(id)} href="#">&raquo;</a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a numeric variable that can be incremented for each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const pages = [...Array(10).keys()].map(i => `${i + 1}`);

function Paginator() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState("");

    return (
        <div className="pagination">
            <a className={active === "prev" ? "active" : ""} onClick={() => setActive("prev")} href="#">
                &laquo;
            </a>
            {pages.map(page => (
                <a key={page} className={active === page ? "active" : ""} onClick={() => setActive(page)} href="#">
                    {page}
                </a>
            ))}
            <a className={active === "next" ? "active" : ""} onClick={() => setActive("next")} href="#">
                &raquo;
            </a>
        </div>
    );
}
```